# Want to use Excel2010 cell column as driver for SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, parameters, cell

Tough to believe I'm the only one but..I want to use the Connection functionality in Excel to connect to a SQL Server database and populate column X based upon using a value in Excel column A as the primary key, but unable to find out how.

I have tried (typing in the command text window)

```
select name 
from pbaTable
where
pbaid = (and this is where I'm stuck)
```

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to find this too!

**step 1:**
Put a question mark into the command text

```
select name 
from pbaTable
where
pbaid = ?
```

**step 2:**
When you refresh the query you will be prompted for the value enter a number - enter something.

**step 3:**
Now go back to the command string in connection properties (ie. connections / properties / definition) - The parameters button should now be enabled - press it

**step 4:**
select the parameter on the left and the "get the value from the following cell" radio button on the right.

**step 4:**
Type in the coordinates of the cell that contains the id eg. =summary!$J$1

Comment: Had tried that before, what I get (in Excel 2010) is a messagebox
that says 'No value given for one or more required parameters' so 
select name from pbatable
where pbaid =?
doesn't work for me...if I type in
select name from pbatable
where pbaid ='PB00000007' it
does work, but I never get the chance to point to an Excel cell

Comment: Make sure under connection properties/definition it says database query and not OLE DB Query - I don't think this is supported by OLE DB Query. Database queries are created with microsoft query

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to import values from Excel col A that you want to participate in your join with SQL Server table pbaTable col pbaid or, the other way around, import data from SQL Server table pbaTable into Excel.

Before you can join or limit data in a where clause, you need the data on the same source, or connected in some virtual manner.